# Best way to share common microservices with multiple teams that will each have their own databases

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, microservices, serverless, serverless-framework

We are working on a serverless project (that uses serverless frameworks). A couple of microservices will be shared across multiple projects (at least 2) but each instance of the microservice will have its own database.

What is the best way to share these microservices? One of the projects uses bitbucket pipelines, another one uses code pipeline.

The AWS accounts for these projects are separate as well.

What is the best way to share the microservices?

Comment: In terms of sharing, are you looking at sharing code between the microservices or the infrastructure that creates the microservices?

Comment: @Norman Look at sharing code for the most part, not sure what the best way would be given different CI-CD processes. Also open to the idea of sharing infrastructure.

Comment: Sharing code doesn't feel like an AWS question but more a question of implementation.  Infrastructure, on the other hand, is a different matter.  You would need to make a decision about how you want to deploy this in a way that's easier to manage across projects.  Perhaps deciding on a specific universal approach.  As you're dealing with multiple accounts, perhaps something like Terraform will make this easier to manage?

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:git], so for the Git answer, all we can say is that when you connect two Git repositories (with fetch or push), the Git repositories will share things at the level of commits. Whether this makes any progress towards your ultimate goal depends on the goal and any other constraints you may have. Probably you should not have used [tag:git] here since Git has nothing to do with microservices.

Answer (score 1):

For shared logic, Lambda Layers are probably the best way to share code.

- Layers are versioned, and match nicely with most package managers. You can publish a new version and then adopt it gradually as needed
- You can deploy lambda code changes and layer changes at the same time, or independently.

If you'd like to dive in further, there are several other options each with pros and cons. Eric Johnson (Sr. Developer Advocate @ AWS) gave a talk at a local meetup that covers this quite well. It's based in SAM, but he and I discuss the parallels available to Serverless Framework users as well. You can find the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxURjGDSbDk)